# Grammar problem

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese

I'd like to ask how can I say in Japanese 'a friend of mine reminded me this great band'?
I thought I should use the ~思い出させてくれる form, but I guess it still too difficult for me.

Comment: Welcome to JLU!  This sounds too much like a "Please translate for me" question, which usually get closed.  I suggest rewording your question to include what you think might be correct, why you think so, and then ask for any pointers.  "Show your research" as it were.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanna give a little tip:
there is this site I use when I wanna look up for direct translations: http://eow.alc.co.jp

You type what you wanna know in the search bar and then a bunch of example sentences will show. For example, if you type "remind", some sentences written in english will show, along with their japanese counterparts. Sometimes it will return 0 results, and sometimes not that many sentences will show up either, but I find it pretty useful for me. There are also these ones I find out recently when I was looking up for a specific pattern:

http://endic.naver.jp
http://ejje.weblio.jp